# Tried every way to install Chinese input but was not successful - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: chinese

I have went through Google and also AskUbuntu forum but yet to find a solution to my issue. The Chinese input I tried to install from Ubuntu is not activated. It appear to be on top of my toolbar "Zh" but was not work at all. I also tried PinYinJoe's method, no go too. Anyone may help me how to activate it for Ubuntu 15.10? I am a new user to Ubuntu, please list the full steps or command. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to language Support
2. go to installed language.
3. find chinese and select them
4. change input system to fcitx and apply
5. log out and log in
6. click the keyboard icon
   7.click configurefcitx
7. click +
   9.find sunpinyin
8. apply them and log out and back in 
   It should them work
  5.